# Sql count of consecutive values

Tags: t-sql, group-by, sql-server-2014-express

I have a table that when i run this query over it

```
SELECT m.Id, m.DateOne, m.DateTwo, (SELECT IIF
  (c.ClubId = 1095 , x.CaptainOne , x.CaptainTwo)
FROM Match x
JOIN Player c on c.Id = x.CaptainOne
JOIN Player d on d.Id = x.CaptainTwo
WHERE x.Id = m.Id  ) AS Captain
FROM Match m
order by DateOne
```

give me an output that looks like this..

```
ID | DateOne    | DateTwo    | Captain
1  | 01/12/2015 |            | 1658
2  | 08/12/2015 |            | 1658
3  | 15/12/2015 | 22/12/2015 | 1658
4  | 02/01/2016 |            | 1703
5  | 09/01/2016 |            | 1703
6  | 16/01/2016 | 23/01/2016 | 1658
7  | 30/01/2016 |            | 1658
8  | 06/02/2016 |            | 1658
9  | 13/02/2016 |            | 1658
10 | 20/02/2016 |            | 1703
```

i then want to use these results to further narrow the output to look like this

```
Captain   | Date(Min)  | Date(Max)  | Count
1658      | 01/12/2015 | 22/12/2015 | 3
1703      | 02/01/2016 | 09/01/2016 | 2
1658      | 16/01/2016 | 13/02/2016 | 4
1703      | 20/02/2016 | 20/02/2016 | 1
```

where it is creating a count of consecutive captain while getting the DateOne of the first occurrence and either DateTwo or DateOne if DateTwo is null of the last occurrence.

I hope this makes sense..
Thanks

Comment: is fk_player and captain the same ?

Comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: Try searching for `[gaps-and-islands]` for techniques to identify and number the groups you want. The rest should be easy.

Comment: @TheGameiswar yes they are.. i have updated the question to reflect that..